# Ejemplo singleton en C++ aplicarlo a QT

Tags: c++, qt

Hola quiero aplicar este programa que esta hecho en c++ a QT ya que yo lo hago de otra manera pero parece no ser la correcta. Yo lo que suelo hacer cuando uso este método, el método singleton, lo que hago es crear un objeto estático pero lo que hay que hacer es hacer _instancia al puntero y inicializarlo la primera vez que se llama. El codigo en c++ que estoy intentando adaptar QT o buscar un ejemplo parecido.

```
class GlobalClass
{
    int m_value;
  public:
    GlobalClass(int v = 0)
    {
        m_value = v;
    }
    int get_value()
    {
        return m_value;
    }
    void set_value(int v)
    {
        m_value = v;
    }
};

// Default initialization
GlobalClass *global_ptr = 0;

void foo(void)
{
  // Initialization on first use
  if (!global_ptr)
    global_ptr = new GlobalClass;
  global_ptr->set_value(1);
  cout << "foo: global_ptr is " << global_ptr->get_value() << '\n';
}

void bar(void)
{
  if (!global_ptr)
    global_ptr = new GlobalClass;
  global_ptr->set_value(2);
  cout << "bar: global_ptr is " << global_ptr->get_value() << '\n';
}

int main()
{
  if (!global_ptr)
    global_ptr = new GlobalClass;
  cout << "main: global_ptr is " << global_ptr->get_value() << '\n';
  foo();
  bar();
}
```

Alguien que sepa al respecto ya que me vendría muy bien un ejemplo parecido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Un ejemplo simple de Singleton es el siguiente:

```
//GlobalClass.h

class GlobalClass
{
public:
  static GlobalClass* get()
  {
    if ( m_instance == nullptr )
    {
      m_instance = new GlobalClass;
    }
    return m_instance;
  }
  void set_value( int value )
  {
    m_value = value;
  }

  int get_value()
  {
    return m_value;
  }

  ~GlobalClass()
  {
    delete m_instance;
  }

private:
  GlobalClass() : m_value( 0 )
  {
  }

  static GlobalClass* m_instance;

  int m_value;
};

GlobalClass* GlobalClass::m_instance = nullptr;
```

Para usarlo simplemente:

```
GlobalClass::get()->set_value(2);
auto val = GlobalClass::get()->get_value();
```

Comment: pero para qt como sería?

Comment: A qué te refieres con que cómo seria para QT?

Comment: vale no invalida qt con c++ entonces una pregunta importo el header y incluyo en el main function lo siguiente: GlobalClass::get()->set_value(2);
auto val = GlobalClass::get();???

Comment: Había una errata en el código, para obtener el valor: auto val = GlobalClass::get()->get_value();
Y sí, incluir el header (no te olvides de añadir #pragma once) y como has dicho.

Answer (score 0):

Dr. Stroustrup recomenda que, el lugar de un "singleton", uses una funcción que devuelva una referencia a un objeto local static.  Él da este ejemplo:

```
X& myX()
{
    static X my_x {3};
    return my_x;
}
```

https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Ri-singleton

Otra alternativa es un archivo de cabezera que he escrito:  https://github.com/wkaras/c-plus-plus-misc/blob/master/ORD_INIT/ord_init.h .
Se puede usar para garantizar el orden de inicialisación, aunque los objectos están en unidades de compilación distintas.